# Retrieve data with attr()

Tags: jquery

I need to retrieve the data from data-id attribute, but it does not work, is anything wrong with the quotes ?

From Jquery:

```
var quantity_id=$(this).attr('data-id');
```

Data to retrieve:

```
echo'<select name="quantity" class="quantity" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">';
```

Thanks in advance for any solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(this).data('id')` to get the data value

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
   $(this).data('id')
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine:

```js
function update(el) {
  console.log( $(el).attr('data-id'), $(el).data('id') );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange='update(this)' data-id="test">
  <option>A
  <option>B
</select>
```

How are you linking `this` to the `<select>`?

Answer (score 0):

jquery does not know what is "this" you should define element use for example.

```
$(".quantity").attr('data-id');
```